# How to configure referral domain in openldap?

Tags: centos, openldap, ldap-query

I have two LDAP server(both are configured using OpenLDAP) running on CentOS 6.2. Suppose hostnames are;
a.xyz.com
b.xyz.com

My requirement is to configure b.xyz.com as referral domain with a.xyz.com.

How can I configure it?

@EJP Thanks for reply. As per OpenLDAP link [OpenLDAP Admin guide](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/referrals.html), I added below entry at a.xyz.com and restart slapd service.

```
dn: dc=develpers,dc=xyz,dc=com
objectClass: referral
objectClass: extensibleObject
dc: subtree
ref: ldap://b.xyz.com/dc=developers,dc=xyz,dc=com
```

Here, 'developers' is ou at b.xyz.com. Therefore, again I added below entry;

```
dn: ou=develpers,dc=xyz,dc=com
objectClass: referral
objectClass: extensibleObject
dc: subtree
ref: ldap://b.xyz.com/ou=developers,dc=xyz,dc=com
```

But still from client end I am not able to query for the user exist on b.xyz.com. I am using ldapadmin client.

Comment: This is answered in the documentation. What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: @TerryGardner What's 'legacy' about OpenLDAP?

Comment: All you've done here is configure b.xyz.com as a referral for that one specific entry. You need to have a look at the various slave and replication configurations.

Comment: Can you provide any document for configuring the same, specific to my requirement?

Comment: Yes, the documentation for slave and replication configurations. You don't seem to be making much of an effort.